# What is a "hint"?

Tags: c++, c++11

On [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace_hint) about [`map::emplace_hint()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace_hint):

> ```c++
> template <class... Args>
> iterator emplace_hint( const_iterator hint, Args&&... args );
> ```
>
> Inserts a new element to the container, using `hint` as a suggestion where the element should go.

So if it is a suggestion does that mean that the implementation doesn't *have* to place the element there? What exactly is a hint?

Comment: Doesn't matter, every implementation I know of ignores it 100%

Comment: @MooingDuck I know libstdc++ checks the positions before hand and if it can it uses it. Otherwise it just does a regular insert.

Comment: @MooingDuck: libc++ does the same thing as libstdc++.

Comment: Oh, maybe I was thinking of `allocate`.

Comment: Suppose you wan't to insert a list of sorted elements to the map. You can use the position of the previously inserted element to hint the container where the next element would be instead of searching again from the root

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally, insertions into a tree-based map (like `std::map`) requires a O(log n) lookup to find the correct insertion point. If the correct insertion point is adjacent to your provided hint, you can save the O(log n) lookup and the operation is O(1) instead.

The usual use case for this is for inserting an item when no existing item for the given key exists. Then, rather than using `.find()` (which returns `.end()` if the item is not found), you use `.lower_bound()` to find the existing key (which returns an iterator to the insertion point, if the key isn't found). Then if the key doesn't exist, you use that iterator for hinted insertion.

Comment: Can you please explain how this could be done in amortized O(1) time (as indicated in cppreference)? Doesn't it need to check whether the hint is the correct insertion point and such check would cost O(lg n)?

Comment: @JasonL No, remember that these iterators are bidirectional. So you simply check the iterator's previous spot, and see if it is suitable (as regards the key ordering) for inserting the entry. If the hint is incorrect, then you fall back to the O(log n) unhinted insertion.

Comment: I don't understand the usual case. `std::map::emplace` will insert only if the key doesn't exist. There is no need to call `find()` or `lower_bound()`

Answer (score 11):

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace_hint) is not accurate about [`map::emplace_hint()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace_hint).  However it should be excused for being so, as at one point prior to C++11, the draft explicitly granted permission for the implementation to ignore the hint:

From [N3225](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3225.pdf), Table 102:

> ... Implementations are permitted to ignore the hint.

Fortunately this was corrected by [LWG 1253](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#1253) and in C++11 and forward reads:

> ... The element is inserted as close as possible to the position just prior to `p`.
>
> logarithmic in general, but amortized constant if the element is inserted right before `p`

So the "hint" has teeth now. It **shall** be respected.  Though note, these comments only apply to the associative containers (map, multimap, set, multiset).

In C++98/03 the "hint" was improperly used for `insert`.  But that was corrected by [N1780](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1780.html), and that wording was subsequently adopted for `emplace_hint`.

Implementations continue to be permitted to ignore the hint for the unordered containers.  And this is for good reason.  There is no good implementation strategy for taking advantage of the hint for the unordered containers.  The hint is there just to provide compatibility with the associative containers in container-generic code.

### Update

Somewhere over the years [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace_hint) has updated its documentation and is now correct:

> Inserts a new element to the container as close as possible to the position just before hint.

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` is an associative container that keeps its *key-value* pairs sorted with respect to *key*. Insertion is of O(logN) complexity, because of costs associated with lookup. But by providing an hint, an *iterator* where to start to search - insertion can occur in amortized constant time instead of logarithmic time.